# Laradock compiling error when docker try to install tokenizer

Tags: php, laravel, docker, laradock

When i try to use `docker compose up` for `Laradock` i'm getting this error and deleting all of images and containers couldn't resolve this problem:

```
153.2 creating libtool
153.3 appending configuration tag "CXX" to libtool
153.4 configure: patching config.h.in
153.4 configure: creating ./config.status
153.4 config.status: creating config.h
153.5 make: *** No rule to make target '/usr/src/php/ext/tokenizer/Zend/zend_language_parser.y', needed by '/usr/src/php/ext/tokenizer/Zend/zend_language_parser.c'.  Stop.
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c pecl channel-update pecl.php.net;   docker-php-ext-install mysqli mbstring pdo pdo_mysql xml pcntl;   if [ $(php -r \"echo PHP_MAJOR_VERSION;\") = \"8\" ] && [ $(php -r \"echo PHP_MINOR_VERSION;\") = \"1\" ]; then     php -m | grep -q 'tokenizer';   else     docker-php-ext-install tokenizer;   fi" did not complete successfully: exit code: 2
```

Comment: Still need a tiny bit more context: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example which Dockerfile was Docker working on? (name/directory). Do you really need that container? `docker-compose up` is a bit broad command, especially for Laradock. What if you do `docker-compose up nginx workspace mariadb php-fpm redis` will that give no errors?